# Optimal Mana Decay Time

Tags: asktheexperts

A node can get mana from the node owner IOTA and mana from processing other people's txs.

The decay time mostly influences the second mana source as you can just resend your own IOTA again.

What thoughts/factors go into optimizing this decay time?

Answer (score 1):

The optimal time will vary depending on your neighbors. It would be best to synchronize the numbers with your neighbors by collaborating with them.